# ITK: find out what kind of image it is

Tags: c++, itk

I'm pretty sure in things like Matlab & Python, you can read an image in, and right outta the box, it will tell you the dimensions of the image and all sorts of stuff.  And then if you want to find out if it's 16 bit or 8 bit, or a labelled or binary mask, I think you have to read the image as an array or something to determine that.

I'm new to ITK.  I'm looking through the documentation, and I'm not seeing what I want, maybe because I'm new to it.  Can somebody please tell me -- how to use ITK to find these things about an image:

- Is it 16 bit or 8 bit?
- Is it a labelled or binary mask?

Thank you!

Comment: Look at this [example](https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/IO/ReadUnknownImageType)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved.**  Thank you @wasthishelpful

> Look at this [example](https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/IO/ReadUnknownImageType)

Comment: I think the answer needs to be from another person to mark it checked